# Double values are displayed for registered arrays in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

## What we want to solve

I am confused. I am trying to display array values on the screen. The array does indeed have the correct values, but when I navigate to another page and back, or some event occurs, the values displayed on the screen double. However, as soon as I refresh the screen, it returns to the correct value. I would like to know the cause and how to solve this problem.

[image]

This is the first screen. At this point, the values are correct.
However, when you go through the link and then come back, the value has increased. Reloading will return it. There is no error.

[image]

## Code

**flow**

① Open page

② Get values from the server with mounted

③ commit to manage the retrieved value with state

**template**

```js
      <v-col cols="9" class="pl-0">
        <v-sheet height="600">
          <v-calendar
            ref="calendar"
            v-model="value"
            color="primary"
            type="week"
            :events="events"
            :event-ripple="false"
            locale="ja-jp"
            :day-format="(timestamp) => new Date(timestamp.date).getDate()"
            :month-format="(timestamp) => (new Date(timestamp.date).getMonth() + 1) + ' /'"
            @mousedown:event="startDrag"
            @click:event="showEvent"
            @mousedown:time="startTime"
            @mousemove:time="mouseMove"
            @mouseup:event="endDrag"
            @mouseleave.native="cancelDrag"
          >
```

**script**

```js
  computed: {
    ...mapState('schedule', ['events', 'selectedEvent']),

  mounted () {

   // ② Get values from the server with mounted

    this.$axios.$get(url.SCHEDULE_API)
      .then((response) => {
        let data
        response.forEach((res) => {
          data = {
            id: res.id,
            name: res.name,
            color: res.color,
            start: res.start,
            end: res.end,
            updated_at: res.created_at,
            timed: res.timed,
            long_time: res.long_time,
            post_id: res.post_id,
            post_item_id: res.post_item_id
          }

       // ③ commit to manage the retrieved value with state
          this.$store.commit('schedule/setEvent', data)
        })
      })
  },
```

**store**

```js
export const state = () => ({
 // ③ commit to manage the retrieved value with state
  events: [],
・
・
・

})
export const mutations = {
・
・
・
  setEvent (state, payload) {
    state.events.push(payload)
  },
・
・
・
```

Comment: Will need some code to find the problem. What is the code for endering array etc?

Comment: @MuhammadAmmar  I'm sorry. I added a code that might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

> The array does indeed have the correct values, but when I navigate to another page and back, or some event occurs,  the values displayed on the screen double...

The array has the correct values in the store. When you navigated away, and came back, the component was re-`mounted`, calling the API again, which in turn called the `setEvent` mutation AGAIN, which pushes the new response data to the store, and thus resulted in double values.

> ... However, as soon as I refresh the screen, it returns to the correct value. I would like to know the cause and how to solve this problem.

"Refreshing" the page results in a fresh store, the `mounted` hook of the component gets called again and you end up with correct values.

---

From what I can gather, you **should** not store the data in the store. This data is private to the component I believe, and should only be loaded and stored in the component's own state when the component loads.

Comment: Thank you for your response, we are using store for API communication and storing the return value in the state event, so we are managing events in store. If we are not allowed to manage the value in store, wouldn't the API communication have to be done within the component?
Is that the correct way?

Comment: I suggest you read up on [Global State Management](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html) and when to use it. To sum it up, you only need to use State Management when you truly want to store something that multiple components will use and rely on. So you have to ask yourself is this data supposed to be global? If yes, then you can store it onto the store, but if the API generally always returns the updated data set, then instead of pushing the data to the `events` array, you should always replace the already stored information.

Comment: Also, I do not understand what you mean by "API Communication". You are currently calling the API in the component thats communication to me and you are storing the data it returns in a global store. Before you store anything in the global state, you should have a very good reason like, multiple components rely on the data and sending props down to siblings, children, and children of children would be too tedious and unfeasible.